# Match a letter and a number in a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to match a string in a specific word. 
For example:

A B~A C D A2D2B (A2)

My jquery code supposed to work if a number is present beside the letter, output must be capitalized. And I want the result to match only the single letters every word, but if a number is present take that number and match it with the letter beside it.

Right now my current output is this:

> hay bee~hay see day    A2D2B (HAY)

Result must be:

> hay bee~hay see day    HAY DAY BEE (HAY)

My Javascript code:

```
 $("button.btn#converter").click(function() {

   var original = $('span[style="color: #660000;"]').text();

   var first = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A2','B2','C2','D2'];
   var second = ['hay', 'bee', 'see', 'day', 'HAY', 'BAY', 'SEE','DAY'];

   var result = $.map(first, function(v) {
     return new RegExp('\\b'+v+'\\b', 'g');
   });


   $('span[style="color: #660000;"]').text(function(i, val) {
     $.each(first, function(i) {
       val = val.replace(result[i], second[i]);
     });
     return val;
   });


 });
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akoni/knp1fcwj/

Comment: You need to use a regex method like `match()`, `exec()`, `test()` etc. Not return a regex object in your `map()`

Comment: You need to move the letters with number elements to the start of the `first`array, otherwise, when you have for example `A2` the `A` regex will replace `A` and you'll only remain with a `2`. Basically, you have to first replace the elements that contain other elements.

Comment: Also, `\b`means *word boundary* which means that none of the regex-es will mach any of the elements in `A2D2B`

Comment: I'm amazed people understand what you're trying to do. I can't see any relationship's at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your output has some spaces which the input is not presented, I add some check logic for that.

As per comments, it could convert back now.

Edit: Added a new case `B(wow)`. I changed the regular expressions to capture all case of converted or unconverted text and brackets as well and the space detect logic.

```js
var first = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'];
var second = ['hay', 'bee', 'see', 'day', 'HAY', 'BAY', 'SEE', 'DAY'];
var $span = $('span[style="color: #660000;"]')
var isConverted = false
var spaceArray = []
for(var i=0;i<$span.length;i++){
  spaceArray.push([])
}

$("button.btn#converter").click(function() {
  $.each($span, function(spanIndex, ele) {
    var text = $(ele).text()
    var reg = isConverted ? /([a-zA-Z]+\d?|\W)/g : /([a-zA-Z]{1}\d?|\W)/g
    var textArray = []
    var spaceIndex = 0;
    var convertIndex = 0;
    
    // find all matches as an array
    var matches = text.match(reg)
    $.each(matches, (arrayIndex, t) => {
      var _first = isConverted ? second : first
      var _second = isConverted ? first : second

      // find the index of match text in first array
      var i = _first.indexOf(t)
  
      // if captured char is not in both array
      if(i == -1){
        textArray.push(t)
        return;
      }

      // check if the next char is non-character
       var char = text[text.indexOf(t) + t.length] || " "

      var replace = _second[i]   
      var index = text.indexOf(t)
      
      // if next char is not a non-character, then add a space after it
      if(isConverted){
        if(spaceArray[spanIndex].length>0){
          if(spaceArray[spanIndex][0] == convertIndex){
            matches.splice(arrayIndex,1)
            spaceArray[spanIndex].shift()
          }
        }
      }
      else{
        if (!/\W/.test(char)) {
          replace = replace + " "
          spaceArray[spanIndex].push(convertIndex)
        }
      }
      
      text = text.substr(index+t.length, text.length)
      
      t = t.replace(t, replace)
      convertIndex++;
      textArray.push(t)
    })
    text = textArray.join('')
    $(ele).text(text)
  })
  $('#converter').text(isConverted ? 'Magic' : 'Original')
  isConverted = !isConverted
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: #660000;">A&nbsp; &nbsp; B~A2D2&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;C&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;D</span>
<br />
<span style="font-family: &quot;georgia&quot; , &quot;times new roman&quot; , serif;">Sample Text Here<br /><span style="color: #660000;">A2D2B&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; C&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; (A2)</span></span><br />
<span style="font-family: &quot;georgia&quot; , &quot;times new roman&quot; , serif;">Sample Text Here<br /><span style="color: #660000;">B~A2D2</span></span><br />
<span style="color: #660000;">C~DC</span><br />
<span style="color: #660000;">B(wow)</span><br />

<br/>
<button class="btn" id="converter">Magic</button>
```

Comment: Wow. You're so meticulous. I like your answer too. But there will be a weird output if you will change the input to B~A2D2

Comment: I added the input you mentioned but I couldn't find out it's a weird output.

Comment: I mean the output became "bee~HAY day AY" instead of bee~HAYDAY

Comment: But it displayed the correct output in the demo above.

Comment: Yep. The above is working, but when I change the value of B~A 
to B~A2D2. This is the output: https://i.imgur.com/nvzaXlg.png

Comment: And I also noticed why the jquery code runs fine even though you didn't put semicolons

Comment: OK, I update as per your comment, and semicolons are optional in most case.

Comment: Mindblown. How did you learned all this stuff? Please make "Magic" to another text once clicked and remove the spaces My first post has typo. I know how to do this but in just a simple way. I want to know your method.

Comment: As per your comment, I changed the method to convert back to original text.

Comment: I found a bug in your code. If we have the input "C~DC", the output becomes "C~undefined"

Comment: Update and fix it.

Comment: Thank you Hikaru. I appreciate your effort

Comment: Sorry for bothering. But I found another bug. Undefined result if the input is "B(wow)".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the current approach is that the single character elements are replaced first. A string like `A2` is matched by both the `A` and `A2` element and since `A` comes first, you'll end up with `hay2`.

To fix that, you'll need to replace the elements that contain the most characters first (that contain other elements).

Here is an example:

```js
 $("button.btn#converter").click(function() {
   var first = ['A2','B2','C2','D2', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
   var second = ['HAY', 'BAY', 'SEE','DAY', 'hay', 'bee', 'see', 'day'];
   
   // Create a single regex that contains all the elements as groups
   var pattern = new RegExp(first.map(function(v){
     return "(" + v + ")";
   }).join("|"), "g");

   $('span[style="color: #660000;"]').text(function(i, val) {
     return val.replace(pattern, function(g){
       return second[first.indexOf(g)];
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: #660000;">A&nbsp; &nbsp; B~A&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;C&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;D</span>
<br />
<span style="font-family: &quot;georgia&quot; , &quot;times new roman&quot; , serif;">Sample Text Here<br /><span style="color: #660000;">A2D2B&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; C&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; (A2)</span></span><br />
<span style="font-family: &quot;georgia&quot; , &quot;times new roman&quot; , serif;">Sample Text Here</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="btn" id="converter">Magic</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Titus. Thanks for your answer. It really helped me. I have another problem I can't change back to the original string after its converted. I apllied your logic, but it seems not to work
Here's the jsfiddle I have: https://jsfiddle.net/akoni/knp1fcwj/53/

Comment: Oh, never mind. I manage to find a solution. https://jsfiddle.net/akoni/knp1fcwj/56/
If you have a better way, your time is always appreciated